# Htaccess deny access to specific page for some IPs

Tags: .htaccess

I have this secret page:

```
 mysite.com/secret
```

I don't want following bots to index this page. Here are the IPs that should be denied access:

```
195.154.126.0/24
195.154.127.0/24
168.119.64.245
168.119.64.246
```

How can I make this work?
I want to block only this page to only these IPs. These IPs should be able to access other pages.

Solution has to be within htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific section, where you deny access to the specific file for these ip addresses:

```
<Files "secret">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from 195.154.126.0/24  195.154.127.0/24  168.119.64.245  168.119.64.246
</Files>
```

Reference:

Files: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files

Deny: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny